# replace specific charater('g') when opening a file with vi(vim)

Tags: vim

I'm suffering from editing a file because I have to replace a specific letter, 'g' at the first character in a first line of the file whenever I open a file with vi(vim).
I've installed Ubuntu 18.04:LTS on a server and then installed vim (sudo apt install vim). After that, I try to edit some files with vi(vim).
However the first letter of the file has been changed to a specific character('g') every time I open a file with vi.
I'm afraid I try to post an error screen but I'm not allowed to post the picture file because of low my reputation.

What is the problem?
I was so frustrated that I checked the link on vi. The vi I'm using is vim.basic. The interesting is that it's OK when I open a file with vim.tiny.
The version of vim is like this.
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Apr 10 2018 21:31:58)
For your information, I don't connect the server directly to the console, but I use it over the network with a X-window manager called mobaXterm.
I really need a help and any comments.
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you have a terminal misconfiguration? What's the value of the TERM variable in mobaXterm and at the server? Try installing ncurses-term on the server

Comment: Can you upload the image somewhere (try http://imgur.com) and then link to it? We can then edit the image into your question.

Comment: Looking at system variables, it said $TERM=xterm. So I changed TERM=ansi then it works well. Thanks.